# Two 4G sim enabled simultaneously (Jio & Airtel) - Samsung Galaxy On Max

Tags: samsung, ota-update, 4g

I have Samsung Galaxy On Max and inserted two different carrier SIM cards that are Jio4g and Airtel. It has been written that this device is dual sim 4g. It was working fine till I was using Jio4g as my LTE network and for mobile data as well but when i recharged my Airtel sim card and switched it to 4g my Jio sim disabled(Jio doesn't have 3g/2g connectivity). So it means i can use only one sim as 4g enabled.

On the basis of device model, it support 4g SIM on both slots but not at same time. It means it does have SoC that can handle LTE networks on both SIMs so,

My concern is,  Can Samsung provide some update so that users can use both SIM as 4g(LTE) simultaneously?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is something like DSDV i.e. Dual SIM Dual VoLTE. Unfortunately, your smartphone does not support it and it will not be possible for Samsung to push an OTA update to enable it. 
The chipset itself is not capable of connecting both SIM cards to 4G networks at the same time. One has to fall-back to 3G/2G.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with Jio 4G and not with Samsung.

As observed, Vodafone Airtel or Airtel and Idea 4G SIMs work perfectly fine with dual SIM. Reliance Jio won't remain active if mobile data is taken from another SIM card on the device. You **must** access internet services from Jio 4G to keep it enabled.

If you want to use both of your SIM cards, then place JIO4G on SIM1 and Airtel on SIM2.